# How to handle click on specific button in loop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, dom-events

I have created following design:

[image]

Here is the react js code:

```
 {this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betDetails.data.map(
                (value, index) => {
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                          <button
                            className="info-button"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            href="#collapseExample"
                            role="button"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="collapseExample"
                            // onClick={
                            //   value.betId != null
                            //     ? _this.getBetIdDetails(value.betId)
                            //     : value.childId != null
                            //     ? _this.getBetIdDetails(value.childId)
                            //     : ""
                            // }
                          >
                       </div>
                       })}
```

Here I am trying following task
If I click on one button it should expand the box
But if I click on one button all boxes are expanding.
If I call some method on click its getting called infinitely

[image: button click expanding all boxes]

Can someone help me to correct the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function on button click. I think it was calling infinitely because you were not passing a reference to the function.

```
{this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betDetails.data.map(
  (value, index) => (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-end" key={index}>
      <button
        className="info-button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        href="#collapseExample"
        role="button"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseExample"
        onClick={
          value.betId != null
            ? () => _this.getBetIdDetails(value.betId)
            : value.childId != null
            ? () => _this.getBetIdDetails(value.childId)
            : () => {}
        }
      >
    </div>
  )
)}
```

You were also missing the `key` prop on div

EDIT:
One button is opening all the boxes because they all have the same IDs and controls.
To make the IDs and controls unique, you can do something like this:

```
{this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betDetails.data.map(
  (value, index) => (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-end" key={index}>
      <button
        className="info-button"
        data-toggle={`collapse${index}`}
        href={`#collapseExample${index}`}
        role="button"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls={`collapseExample${index}`}
        onClick={
          value.betId != null
            ? () => _this.getBetIdDetails(value.betId)
            : value.childId != null
            ? () => _this.getBetIdDetails(value.childId)
            : () => {}
        }
      >
    </div>
  )
)}
```

Comment: Thank you Ansh . Now there are no infinite calls but still on click on one button all other boxes also expanding. Can you please share what is wrong ? I think part needs modification                                                                                                                     
        `data-toggle="collapse"
        href="#collapseExample"
        role="button"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseExample" `
I tried use index but it is not working.

Comment: I have updated the answer, maybe that will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems pretty straightforward. You're directly executing a function in the onClick. That's why all of them are getting executed. You just need to change the onClick as follows:

```
onClick = { ()  => {
    if(value.betId != null){
     _this.getBetIdDetails(value.betId)
} else if (value.childId != null){
     _this.getBetIdDetails(value.childId)
} else {return ""} }
```

Answer (score 0):

To each div you need to give unique id, may be primary key of that row, and when that button is clicked pass the id to the opening function, and append that to id of that div to open. Hope it helps. This will go like this:-

```
  onclick=handler(1)
```

div id should be like this:- open1, open2
handler should be like this:-

```
handler(id) => idofelement+id open
```